# Tikz-Uml hidden lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml, smartdiagram, pgflayers

I have problems with drawing an use-case diagram with `tikz-uml`.
There is no problem if I only use `tikz-uml`, but if include the `smartdiagram` package too.

I've had some errors telling me that the connections layer was required, so I set the layers.

But now I've got the problem that the lines inside the systembox are hidden!

Did i miss a layer? (Foreground does not work, it is telling me that this layer is not in my list.

With `smartdiagram` it looks like :

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
%\usepackage{smartdiagram}


\begin{document}
%\pgfsetlayers{connections,background,main,smart diagram arrow back}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\resizebox {\columnwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlsystem}{Testsystem}
    \umlusecase[x=-3]{Betankung beauftragen}
    \umlusecase[x=3, y =-1]{Flugzeug betanken}
    \umlusecase[x=-2,y=-2]{Betankung bestätigen}

    \end{umlsystem}

    \umlactor[x=-8]{Initiator}

    \umlactor[x=8]{Mitarbeiter A}

    \umlassoc{Initiator}{usecase-1}
    \umlassoc{Initiator}{usecase-3}
    \umlassoc{Mitarbeiter A}{usecase-2}

    \end{tikzpicture}

}
\caption{Use-Case 1.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `connections` layer to the top of the stack it seems to work fine, i.e.

```
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,smart diagram arrow back,connections}
```

Alternatively, swap the order of the package loading so `tikz-uml` comes last:

```
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
```

I guess `smartdiagram` overwrites the layer list, thereby removing a `connections` layer defined by `tikz-uml`. If you're using `smartdiagram` elsewhere, you might up with a similar error there though, in which case you'll need the `\pgfsetlayers` line anyway, I suppose.

Either way, the resulting output for your example is

[image]